# An AC generator can 'lock up' if its timing is off?

Tags: ac, power-electronics, alternator

I believe I read elsewhere on Stack Exchange (Physics or Electrical Engineering) about how an alternating current generator can seize up if the frequency of the current does not match something else in the device?

The commenter said the revolving magnets suddenly want to reverse direction so fast that they barely move back and forth at all?

Comment: This might make sense if it had something to do with a motor. As is, it is a vague description of something you read somewhere.  I am voting to close the question due to lack of detail.

Comment: maybe you read about a stepping motor

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing sounds similar to the issue of starting a synchronous motor, where the voltage of the stator is operating at the motor/generator's nominal frequency, but the inertia of the rotor is too high to "follow" the stator frequency. The magnetic field of the stator causes a slight pull of the rotor while it cycles "away" from the rotor, but the torque induced by the stator on its half cycle toward the rotor counters the initial rotation, resulting in net-zero torque.

I have posted a figure from Stephen Chapman's book "Electric Machinery Fundamentals" which illustrates this well.
Note that induced torque is proportional to the rotor's magnetic field crossed with the stator's:
$$ \tau _{ind} \propto \boldsymbol{B_{R}}\times \boldsymbol{B_{_{S}}} $$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about synchronizing generators, if the frequency was off by 2:1  this could happen. It would probably break something if protection circuitry does not trip.

Normally, in synchronizing manually, one would first match frequency closely, then adjust the phase to almost match before closing the circuit.

Comment: Yup, when the lights stop racing, slow down, then come on and off together, and then when all 3 lights are out, THEN you come online!